# GridView and DropDownlist

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a gridview that when enter to edit mode one of the column change to dropdownlist:

```
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
          DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name">
          </asp:DropDownList>
     </EditItemTemplate>
```

Now i have a `SqlDataSource` with update method that define in this aspx file:

```
<UpdateParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Type="string" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="genre" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

now i want to get the selected value and insert it but when i press the Update button in the row in the gridview i get this error:

```
Could not find control 'DropDownList2' in ControlParameter 'genre'
```

any idea why it happen?

Comment: sqldatasource should be in EditItemTemplate

Comment: But it is a diffrent datasource from SqlDataSource1

Comment: you are populating dropdown from a sqldatasource rite? just try placing that datasource below the dropdown in EditItemTemplate

Comment: It does not matter where you place the SqlDataSource. Unless you're programmatically modifying the SQL data source for every row, there is no point putting it inside a GridView. I always place all my data sources at the end of the ASPx code. ASP is smart enough to know where to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `ControlParameters` only work when the DOM can find the control you're referring to that's within the same branch of the `GridView`. The problem is that Gridviews are a poor way of handling DOM controls because as soon as you go into a "mode" of the GridView like the EDIT mode, the entire DOM structure changes. The DOM by the way, is the **Document Object Model**. Because it's changed, therefore ASP cannot find the control you're referring to.

I've overcome this by doing one of two things.

First see if it works by simply tailing the control name with the `'$'` character.

```
<UpdateParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="MyGridView$DropDownList2" Type="string" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="genre" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

This **sometimes** works if you're lucky.

If not, then you'll need to find the control, get its value and pass it into the SQL parameter programmatically in code behind.

Try something like this (I use C#) ...

```
protected void MyGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   ...
   GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)sender;
   DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownList2");
   if (myDDL != null)
   {
      //assuming your datasource is outside the gridview, you have to find it!
      SqlDataSource sds1 = (SqlDataSource)page.FindControl("myDataSource");
      if (sds1 != null)
      {
         sds1.UpdateParameter["genre"].DefaultValue = myDDL.SelectedValue;
         ... and do your databinding etc
         sds1.Update();
      }
   }
}
```

I always rely on the client-side code (ASPX) to do most of the work for me, like `Bind()`, `Eval()`, etc, but over time you'll realise that to really control your program, you'll have to rely on JavaScript or code behind to do the finer bits. ASP is not always "clever" in doing what you expect it to do.